# Wrapping angular-ui-typeahead breaks the on-select callback

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to wrap AngularUI's [typeahead directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) with my own directive so I can package up some shared data/behavior for easier reuse in my app: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B4axmy2nV3LbZFpC7tfq?p=preview)

In the `onSelect` callback, why does the correct value only show up after the timeout?

For reference, this works correctly without the wrapping directive: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBFiJ8yfYc1LWKyozLf7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use `=` inside an isolate scope directive so that the bound function is called only after the model is updated:

```
scope : {
    selectedModel : "=",
    onSelect : "="
}
```

<kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IKqs8okBKgudNjS7BXKT?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Actually, using '=' causes onSelect to loop infinitely (add a console.log in this.onSelect to observe that). Passing in on-select="ctrl.onSelect" stops the infinite looping, but we'd be back to square one. Plus I don't like declaring the function without the parentheses as it's different from the regular way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an ampersand in the directive and pass the item in the html. From the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) "The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time. Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which contains a function call. Because of this, & bindings are ideal for binding callback functions to directive behaviors."

**Isolated scope in directive:**

```
scope: { 
onSelect: '&'
}
```

**Html**

```
<input autocomplete="off"
placeholder="Enter &ldquo;jo&rdquo; and pick something"
ng-model="selectedModel"
typeahead="v as v.name for v in vendors | filter:$viewValue"
typeahead-on-select="onSelect({item: $item})" />
```

Callback function should take an item

```
function myCallback(item) {
console.log(item);
}
```